# iterate for loop over dataframe rows

Tags: python, pandas, list

I am new to python and learning to use dataframes and list comprehensions.
I have the following dataframe:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'names':[[['Hans Peter'],['Harry Potter']],[['bla bla'],['some string']]]})
```

now i want to split each sublist into words.
For a single list of lists i could use

```
x=[['Hans Peter'],['Harry Potter'],['bla bla'],['some string here']]
res=[]
for list in x:
    res.append(str(list[0]).split())
```

but how can i iterate this over a dataframe? i think i have to build a list comprehensions and then use the `apply()` method to overgo the `.append`? but i dont know how to do this.
I would build the list comprehension for a single list like this:

```
res = [str(list[0]).split for list in x]
```

but i get a list containing this functions:

```
[<function str.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)>,...]
```

the expected output for a DataFrame would be

```
 0 [['Hans','Peter],['Harry','Potter']]
 1 [['bla','bla'],['some','string']]
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: just updated ;)

Comment: In your list comprehension, you're making two common errors: You're using `.split` instead of `.split()` (which is why it's returning a function instead of a result), and you're using `list` as a variable, which can shadow the built-in `list` type and cause issues

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need to call the `split` function, because otherwise `str.split` is an object:

```py
''.split
<built-in method split of str object at 0x1005a3ab0>

''.split() # call with parentheses
[]
```

Second, you need to get down to the sub-lists within `names`. You can simulate this with a for loop first:

```py
for x in df1.names:
    for a in x:
        print(a)

['Hans Peter']
['Harry Potter']
['bla bla']
['some string']
```

You'll be left still with lists, so you can use `a.pop()` to get the strings out, then use `str.split()` on the result of `pop()`:

```py
df1.names = [[a.pop().split() for a in x] for x in df1.names]

df1
                              names
0  [[Hans, Peter], [Harry, Potter]]
1      [[bla, bla], [some, string]]
```